# The view Insertemp.views.Insertrecord didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, mysql, django, phpmyadmin

I'm not sure what is coursing the problem....

The view Insertemp.views.Insertrecord didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

***views.py***

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from Insertemp.models import EmpInsert
from django.contrib import messages

def Insertrecord(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('empname') and request.POST.get('email') and request.POST.get('country'):
            saverecord = EmpInsert()
            saverecord.empname = request.POST.get('empname')
            saverecord.email = request.POST.get('email')
            saverecord.country = request.POST.get('country')
            saverecord.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Record saved successfully...!')
            return render(request, 'Index.html')
        else:
            return render(request, 'Index.html'),
```

I have change the code....

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from Insertemp.models import EmpInsert
from django.contrib import messages

def Insertrecord(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('empname') and request.POST.get('email') and request.POST.get('country'):
            saverecord = EmpInsert()
            saverecord.empname = request.POST.get('empname')
            saverecord.email = request.POST.get('email')
            saverecord.country = request.POST.get('country')
            saverecord.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Record saved successfully...!')
            return render(request, 'templates/Index.html', {})
        else:
            return render(request, 'templates/Index.html', {})
```

but still it doesn't display what it should...

***Index.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Insert new Record</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Create or New record Insert into MySQL(PhpMyAdmin)</h1>
    <h2>Python Django web Programming</h2>
    <hr>
    <form method="POST">
        {% cdrf_token %}
        Employee Name : <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="empname" required>
        Email : <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>
        country : <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Country" name="country" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Insert record">

        {% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
                <h2 style="color: green;">{{message}}</h2>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </form>
    <hr>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give default response, in example for `GET` requests:

```
def Insertrecord(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('empname') and request.POST.get('email') and request.POST.get('country'):
            (...)
            return render(request, 'templates/Index.html', {})
        else:
            return render(request, 'templates/Index.html', {})
    return render(request, 'templates/Index.html', {})  # new
```

Comment: your new statement worked perfect, I appreciate... but I also had to remove 'templates/' from 'templates/Index.html' in each return statement.

Comment: You didn't share your tree so I couldn't relate. It depends where you store it and what you have set in your settings.py. I'm glad that it helped. You might tick it as the correct answer.